# how to send images and binary documents using Azure Pub Sub ? is it supported?

Tags: azure, publish-subscribe

how to send images and binary documents using Azure Pub Sub ? is it supported or only text ?

trying to send images and documents to azure pub sub. is there any limitation about it ? any example  using python to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-web-pubsub/key-concepts#terms):

> Messages can be in plain text, binary, or JSON format and have a **maximum size of 1 MB.**

Now, if we take a look at the introduction it states:

> The Azure Web PubSub Service helps you build real-time messaging web applications using WebSockets and the publish-subscribe pattern easily.

and I wonder you really want to build a real time service for images and binaries? What is your use case for this?

Comment: hi Peter, thanks for the response. Didn´t find the information in the docs. thanks. The use case is a chat where the chat can share different types of files. any suggestion on that ?

Comment: You might want to upload the files to a blob account, have a blob triggered function send a pub sub message when the blob is uploaded and then display the file in the chat.